# Change div content with value of array in each function

Tags: jquery

I have been trying this from past many hours, I know this is possible, what I am doing is, I have a div which needs to be updated with the data in array. Below is my code:

```
var data = $.trim('test1, test2, test3');
var data_array = data.split(',');
 $.each(data_array, function(key,value) {
   $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").replaceWith(value);
 });
```

while this is the HTML div where I need to put the content

```
<div id ="waitingcategoryinsert">
   <img src ="../includes/templates/snowwhite/images/loading.gif"/>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

This function updating div with only first value of array i.e. "test1" and I want to display all 3 values one by one with a delay. I have tried it with settimeout() function too, but that too didn't work. Please help me out where am I going worng?, thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected result here? What's the point of trimming a string with no beginning/ending whitespace, splitting it on `,` then only taking the first instance? Sounds like you just want `$("#waitingcategoryinsert span")[0].outerHTML = "test1, test2, test3";`

Comment: This question is unclear, improve it by giving concrete sample of what you are looking for

Comment: The first element of array in first iteration replaces the span and no span is available for subsequent elements, If you want subsequent elements and span then use append. http://jsfiddle.net/N4NJs/

Comment: @Adil I want to show data of array in span one by one

Comment: Do you want this, http://jsfiddle.net/N4NJs/1/

Comment: @Adil not exactly, what I want is "test2" should replace "test1" and so on..

Comment: Use html() or text() instead of append then, http://jsfiddle.net/N4NJs/2/

Comment: @Adil yes, I have used that and it works... :) thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add value to span, Try this:

```
  $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").html(value);
```

To remove span and keep appending array element:

```
  if($("#waitingcategoryinsert span").length)
      $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").remove();
  $("#waitingcategoryinsert").append(value) ;
```

**Update:** Show elements with delay:

```
  var i=1;
  $.each(data_array, function(key,value) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").html(value);
   },500 + ( i * 500 ));
   i=i+1;
  });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm7CQ/1/)**

Comment: Then what is the purpose of each loop? I guess, should be maybe: `$("#waitingcategoryinsert span").eq(key).html(value);`

Comment: @A.Wolff:updated the answer. Not exactly sure what OP wants. whether to add those elements in span or remove span and add elements in `#waitingcategoryinsert`

Comment: Ya indeed absolutely not clear what OP is looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff I want to show array's data into span one by one with a time delay

Comment: @NehaMangla Why didn't you put it inside question then???

Answer (score 0):

You just missed.

```
$("#waitingcategoryinsert span").prepend(value)
```

Comment: I have tries that too, but didn't work for me

Comment: updated it with `prepend` try now pls..

Comment: I want to show array value into span one by one with a time delay

Comment: Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Have you achieved it ?

Comment: Yes , it is done now. Thanks for your time and help Mayank

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** instead of `.replaceWith()`:

```
$("#waitingcategoryinsert span").append(value);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ5tu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(data_array, function(key, value) {
    $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").append(value);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/ZXCYL/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use Append property og Jquery to show all result.Because append can have hold all value in it.

```
var data = $.trim('test1, test2, test3');   
var data_array = data.split(',');   
$.each(data_array, function(key,value) {  
$("#waitingcategoryinsert span").append(value);  
});
```